# Calculating two variable inputs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a physics calculator webpage. I need the user to enter the given he has and leave the unknown part that he wants to calculate empty.

For example he has 'a' and 'b' and wants to calculate 'c'.. the empty part has to be calculated.

Here is my code:

```js
function rocCalculator(source, valNum) {
  valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
  var g0 = 9.80665;
  var R = document.getElementById("inputR");

  var QE = document.getElementById("inputQE");
  var Vb = document.getElementById("inputVb");

  if (source == "inputR") {
    Vb.value = (Math.sqrt((valNum * g0) / (Math.sin(2 * QE * Math.PI / 180)))).toFixed(5);
    QE.value = (((Math.asin((valNum * g0) / (Vb * Vb)) * (180 / Math.PI)) / 2)).toFixed(5);

  }
  if (source == "inputQE") {
    Vb.value = (Math.sqrt((valNum * g0) / (Math.sin(2 * QE * Math.PI / 180)))).toFixed(5);
    R.value = ((Vb * Vb * Math.sin(2 * valNum * Math.PI / 180)) / g0).toFixed(5);

  }
  if (source == "inputVb") {
    QE.value = (((Math.asin((R * g0) / (valNum * valNum)) * (180 / Math.PI)) / 2)).toFixed(5);
    R.value = ((Vb * Vb * Math.sin(2 * valNum * Math.PI / 180)) / g0).toFixed(5);

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contentr">
  <div>
    <h2>Roc Calculator</h2>
  </div>

  <div style="margin:0 -16px">
    <p style="margin-left:8px;margin-bottom:4px;">Type a value in any of the fields:</p>
    <div>
      <label>R</label>
      <input id="inputR" type="number" placeholder="R" oninput="rocCalculator(this.id,this.value)" onchange="rocCalculator(this.id,this.value)">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Vb</label>
      <input id="inputVb" type="number" placeholder="Vb" oninput="rocCalculator(this.id,this.value)" onchange="rocCalculator(this.id,this.value)">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>QE</label>
      <input id="inputQE" type="number" placeholder="QE" oninput="rocCalculator(this.id,this.value)" onchange="rocCalculator(this.id,this.value)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is not working.

Comment: "It is not working" is a very poor bug report :). Please read [ask] and help us help you.

Comment: not working because you have NULL on your fist calcul each time, for example `  Vb.value = (Math.sqrt((valNum * g0) / (Math.sin(2 * QE * Math.PI / 180)))).toFixed(5);` **QE** is null. On your last calul **R** is null... no bug but a wrong logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work now, I tried to keep the formulas lined up. I like to avoid arguments whenever possible so I removed them so now I can be called from a button (If you like). The function works very similarly to before, it checks if there an empty and two filled and fills the third.

It also stores the last edited one in case you want to run the function on `oninput`. This will allow you to enter multiple digits in the second input and it can still update the thrid. I found it works a lot better with button vs a live update.

```js
var lastFilled;

function rocCalculator() {
  var g0 = 9.80665;
  
  //Get the inputs
  var R = document.getElementById("inputR");
  var QE = document.getElementById("inputQE");
  var Vb = document.getElementById("inputVb");

  //Vb Empty or was last filled
  if ((Vb.value === '' || lastFilled === 'Vb') && R.value !== '' && QE.value !== '') {
    var RParsed = parseFloat(R.value),
        QEParsed = parseFloat(QE.value);
  
    Vb.value = (Math.sqrt((RParsed * g0) / (Math.sin(2 * QEParsed * Math.PI / 180)))).toFixed(5);
    
    lastFilled = 'Vb';
  //R Empty or was last filled
  } else if ((R.value === '' || lastFilled === 'R') && Vb.value !== '' && QE.value !== '') {
    var VbParsed = parseFloat(Vb.value),
        QEParsed = parseFloat(QE.value);
  
    R.value = ((VbParsed * VbParsed * Math.sin(2 * QEParsed * Math.PI / 180)) / g0).toFixed(5);
    
    lastFilled = 'R';
  //QE Empty or was last filled
  } else if ((QE.value === '' || lastFilled === 'QE') && Vb.value !== '' && R.value !== '') {
  
    var VbParsed = parseFloat(Vb.value),
        RParsed = parseFloat(R.value);
  
    QE.value = (((Math.asin((RParsed * g0) / (VbParsed * VbParsed)) * (180 / Math.PI)) / 2)).toFixed(5);
    
    lastFilled = 'QE';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contentr">
  <div>
    <h2>Roc Calculator</h2>
  </div>

  <div style="margin:0 -0px">
    <p style="margin-left:8px;margin-bottom:4px;">Type a value in any of the fields:</p>
    <div>
      <label>R</label>
      <input id="inputR" type="number" placeholder="R">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Vb</label>
      <input id="inputVb" type="number" placeholder="Vb">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>QE</label>
      <input id="inputQE" type="number" placeholder="QE">
    </div>
    
    <button onclick="rocCalculator()">Calculate</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not know about physics calculator, but code working this way:

```js
  function rocCalculator(source, valNum) {
  valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
  var g0 = 9.80665;
  var R = document.getElementById("inputR").value === '' ? 0 : document.getElementById("inputR").value;

  var QE = document.getElementById("inputQE").value === '' ? 0 : document.getElementById("inputQE").value;
  var Vb = document.getElementById("inputVb").value === '' ? 0 : document.getElementById("inputVb").value;

  if (source == "inputR") {
    document.getElementById("inputVb").value = (Math.sqrt((valNum * g0) / (Math.sin(2 * QE * Math.PI / 180)))).toFixed(5);
    document.getElementById("inputQE").value = (((Math.asin((valNum * g0) / (Vb * Vb)) * (180 / Math.PI)) / 2)).toFixed(5);

  }
  if (source == "inputQE") {
    document.getElementById("inputVb").value = (Math.sqrt((valNum * g0) / (Math.sin(2 * QE * Math.PI / 180)))).toFixed(5);
    document.getElementById("inputR").value = ((Vb * Vb * Math.sin(2 * valNum * Math.PI / 180)) / g0).toFixed(5);

  }
  if (source == "inputVb") {
    document.getElementById("inputQE").value = (((Math.asin((R * g0) / (valNum * valNum)) * (180 / Math.PI)) / 2)).toFixed(5);
    document.getElementById("inputR").value = ((Vb * Vb * Math.sin(2 * valNum * Math.PI / 180)) / g0).toFixed(5);

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contentr">
  <div>
    <h2>Roc Calculator</h2>
  </div>

  <div style="margin:0 -16px">
    <p style="margin-left:8px;margin-bottom:4px;">Type a value in any of the fields:</p>
    <div>
      <label>R</label>
      <input id="inputR" type="number" placeholder="R" onchange="rocCalculator(this.id,this.value)">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Vb</label>
      <input id="inputVb" type="number" placeholder="Vb"  onchange="rocCalculator(this.id,this.value)">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>QE</label>
      <input id="inputQE" type="number" placeholder="QE"  onchange="rocCalculator(this.id,this.value)">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Obs.: Removed tag "oninput" of inputs text, because executed trigger onclick of button.

Comment: It does **NOT** work. Also `oninput` is more appropriate for this than `onchange`...